# How to select distinct rows per group

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, group-by

My table looks as follows:

```
 author_id | doc_id |      lang      
-----------+--------+----------------

        53 |  12642 | English
        53 |  12643 | English
        53 |     75 | French

        55 |  12605 | German
        55 |  12606 | German
        55 |  12596 | English
```

and I need to write a query make a table as follows:

```
 author_id | doc_id |      lang      
-----------+--------+----------------

        53 |  12642 | English
        53 |     75 | French

        55 |  12605 | German
        55 |  12596 | English
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, for each combination of author and language, you want the minimal document id. 
You could group by the columns you want the distinct values of, and apply an aggregate `min` to the other:

```
SELECT   author_id, MIN(doc_id), lang
FROM     docs
GROUP BY author_id, lang
```

Comment: Thank you very much